# I need to prove the monotony and the constraint of the sequence $(a_n)$, and also find its boundary if $a_1= 3/2$; $a_{n + 1}^2 = 3a_n - 2, n ≥ 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, constraints

I need to prove the monotony and the constraint of the sequence $a_n$, and also find its limit if $a_1 = 3/2$; $a_{n + 1}^2 = 3a_n - 2, n ≥ 1$. Should I use the method of mathematical induction here?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: do you mean $$(a_{n+1})^2=3a_n-2$$ with $$a_1=\frac{3}{2}$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner yes, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See that $a_{n+1}^2 - a_n ^2 =3(a_n -a_{n-1})$ which means, $(a_n+a_{n+1})(a_{n+1}-a_n)=3(a_n -a_{n-1})$.
First show that $a_n$ is positive as $a_{n+1}^2 +2>0$
So, the monotony of the sequence depends on the relation between $a_{n+1},a_{n}$, If $a_{n+1}>a_{n} \implies a_{n} > a_{n-1}$ This continues upto $a_2 > a_1$ which is indeed true.Thus the sequence is monotonically increasing.
For boundedness, let for some $k$, $a_k<2$. We have to show by mathematical induction that $a_{k+1} <2$.Indeed $a_{k+1}^2 =3a_k -2 < 3.2 -2=4 \implies a_{k+1} <2$ , Thus the sequence is bounded by $2$.
Suppose $L$ be the limit of this sequence, we have:$L^2-3L+2=0 \implies L=2$